# Simplify a filter clause with many predicates that depend on context

Tags: clojure, format

I am new to Clojure and am still trying to wrap my head around doing things the "Clojure way". One function that I'm currently writing requires me to filter a collection (`pile`) with several predicates, but the set of predicates to use depends on several function arguments (in this case `ref-base` and `single-ended?`). Here is the code I currently have:

```clj
(filter (every-pred
        qcpass?
        (case ref-base
          "C" (if single-ended?
               #(not (reverse? %))
               #(and (properly-paired? %) (or (f1? %) (r2? %))))
          "G" (if single-ended?
               reverse?
               #(and (properly-paired? %) (or (f2? %) (r1? %))))
          nil?) ;; skip all piles if we're in a non-C/G position
        ) pile))
```

I feel that there is probably a better/more concise way to write this, since there is still some repetition of code in there, and a lot of parentheses. I'm also unhappy, aestetically, with the inline functions (`#(..)`) to use `and`/`or`/`not` within a filter. Could I ask for suggestions how to make this whole expression "prettier"?

Comment: SO is not really a code review page. In general i'd move things out and give them names.  E.g the "c-pred?" and "g-pred?" and also the deciding part. Makes it easier to test and to try out in the repl.

Comment: Please edit the question to add some sample input and the desired output.

Comment: Try asking CR-style Clojure questions here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clojure

Comment: @AaronBell you learn something new every day - hadn't seen codereview.stackexchange.com before. I'll keep it in mind next time.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this will be much "prettier" (that is a matter of taste) but here is a suggestion to take apart the logic of `(case ref-base ...)` and `(if single-ended?` so they are not nested:

```
(filter (every-pred qcpass?
                    (let [pred (fn [r f0? f1?]
                                 (if single-ended?
                                   #(= r (reverse? %))
                                   #(and (properly-paired? %)
                                         (or (f0? %) (f1? %)))))]
                      (case ref-base
                        "C" (pred false f1? r2?)
                        "G" (pred true f2? r1?)
                        nil?)))
        pile)
```

I have not tested this code and I don't know if it has bugs.